# NO funciona el input-checkbox

Tags: html, angular

Tengo un proyecto angular, intento agregar en cualquier parte un input-checkbox, pero no se ve reflejado.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="" />Cualquier nombre
```

Adjunto imagen de como se ve en el navegador...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco la ayuda

Comment: Hola ProgramadorNovato, te recomiendo que mires [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y de paso evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada y de paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].